# Spring Servlet HTTP Post request re-send

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, http-post

I'm having a bit of an design and coding problem. 
Step1: I receive an http post request which i save into my db.
2: then i need to resend the the same request. 
3: return the form of the external url. simple jsp side with a redirect to the target_URL (I think thats inconvenient but i'm not sure how else to do that.

My problem is that I'm sending an http post request to an url where i redirect my application user. what would be a better solution. should i send it with my jsp? but how can i get my data there. 
problem #2: is my way to send the post request correct ? 
Thx for any help, I'm kinda lost or blocked today ;)

```
@RequestMapping("/internalData")
    public String paymentReceiveInternal(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

User user = new User();
user.setUserName(request.getParamter("name");

//save user into DB

// resend the request.
URL targetUrl = new URL(VIEW_TARGET_URL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(request.getContentLength()));

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write(urlParameters);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
connection.disconnect();

return VIEW_TARGET_URL;
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The way you are sending the POST looks legit...

Comment: Don't forget `method = RequestMethod.POST` in the `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: when i add the RequestMethod.Post I always get an error. "message:  Request method 'GET' not supported" with "description: The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource." why is that ? but for my http post request send i'm using setRequestMethod("POST"), so this should be a post. but the rest is a GET or what ? kinda confused thx